# How to get the amount of times a element appears on a list Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, variables

I am currently learning python and came upon a problem.

I need to know if a element is part of a list, basically, the frequency of occurrence inside the list:

For example, Suppose I have this list of lists:

```
A = [[1, 2, 4, 5], [2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 4, 5],
     [1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4]]
```

and let's suppose I need to know if the following numbers appear on the list: `[1, 2, 4]`

As you may see, the numbers `[1, 2, 4]` appear on the list, on positions `A[0]`, `A[2]`, and `A[4]` (the order does not matter, just if the three of them appear at the same time). So, the frequency of appearance should be 3.

I've tried to use `any()` to see if there was a way to check if x was part of list A

```
any(x == [1,2,4] for x in  A)
```

Or use for loops, but they only check if *each* individual of x is part of A, but I need to know whether the a certain series of elements appear.

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    count=0
    print("i",i)
    for j in range(len(x[i])):
        print("j",j)
        for k in range(len(A)):
            print("k",k)
            for l in range(len(A[k])):
                if x[i][j]==A[k][l]:
                    count+=1
```

Is there a more efficient way to check this in Python?

Comment: Does the number list you wish to check have unique elements? i.e. should `[1, 2, 4]` consist of unique values?

Comment: @JoonyoungPark yes, it has unique elements. I cannot check, for example, [1, 1, 4], or [2,2,2]

Comment: Okay, then the answer by @Selcuk seems good enough. I upvote it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `set` operations since the order is not important:

```
>>> print(sum(1 for x in A if {1, 2, 4} <= set(x)))
3
```